# error trying to bind ManyToMany relationShip

Tags: java, playframework, many-to-many, ebean

I am using ebean with Play Framework 2.4

I cant understand where is the problem. Here are a simplified version of my two beans:

```
@Entity
public class ArtifactEntry extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @play.data.validation.Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "artifacts")
    public List<TimestampEntry> timestamps = new ArrayList<TimestampEntry>();
}
```

And my other bean:

```
@Entity
public class TimestampEntry extends Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @play.data.validation.Constraints.Required
    @Index
    public String timestamp;

    public Date timestampDate;

    @play.data.validation.Constraints.Required
    @Index
    public String buildNumber;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public ArtifactsList artifacts = new ArtifactsList();

    public static class ArtifactsList extends ArrayList<ArtifactEntry> {

    }
}
```

The error message is:

> 1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error on models.ArtifactEntry.timestamps. mappedBy property [models.TimestampEntry.artifacts] is not a ManyToMany?

**EDIT**: After having researched more, the problem is clearly the fact that "artifacts" is not the immediate type "List" but a subclass of it. Ebean is not that smart. Any solution to this?

Comment: Just shooting... if I remember well I had some problems with inner classes and Ebean some time ago, the solution was moving classes to separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I have edited in my previous post, the problem seem to be that EBeans does not read the type hierarchy of the attributes up to match a ManyToMany relation ship. It simply has to match on both classes.

In a first place, I needed to implement this with an empty class extending ArrayList, so that I can register this class with a custom SimpleFormatter (as I did not want to parse all the List in this way).

I ended up removing the "ArtifactsList" and instead, of using a SimpleFormatter with List, I have changed it to use an AnnotationFormatter, so that only only my annotated attribute gets parsed in this custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `public ArtifactsList artifacts`: this field is expected to be a collection (e.g. `List<ArtifactEntry> artifacts`) but it is not.
What you coded is a bi-directional `OneToMany` and you may want to annotate `artifacts` with `ManyToOne` or convert that field to a collection and keep the `ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: If you see down at the class. ArtifactsList is extending ArrayList... I needed it like that to register a custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

The "mappedBy" side needs to be annotated with @JoinTable to specify which table contains your artifacts.  See this tutorial:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="ARTIFACT_TABLE", 
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TIMESTAMP_ID")}, 
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ARTIFACT_ID")})
public List<ArtifactEntry> artifacts;
```

Comment: does joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns work on Ebean? I think it did not work for me.